# The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context (SharePoint 2010, Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sandbox

I got this problem when I create sandbox solution for SharePoint 2010 using Visual Studio 2010.

Image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/812/sp20102y.jpg/

I use my local machine to create this solution after doing development environment as this post showed ([link](http://blog.raminassar.com/2011/10/14/working-with-sharepoint-2010-projects-on-visual-studio-without-installing-the-server/)). I want to deploy this solution to the server installed SharePoint Server 2010, but Visual Studio 2010 gives me this problem. Can you suggest me a solution for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug.

Check this post:

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/the-name-initializecontrol-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-visual-web-part-sandboxed-bug-fix/